# How can I list column names with rows that only contain value

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

How can I list column names (in one cell) with rows that only contain value (blank not included)?
If possible, separated by a line break.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following formula

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),1,UNIQUE(INDEX(FLATTEN(IF(G2:K5="",,G1:K1)))))
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`CHAR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120)
- [`FLATTEN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198)
- [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.